# CSOM Redirect documents to OfficeWebApp/OfficeOnline with SharepointOnlineCredentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, office365, csom, sharepoint-online

I am currently implementing CSOM methods to access SharePoint stored documents from an MVC site. I could already access lists of documents and each document's properties. What I'm trying to do (and failing miserably at that) is to provide an Office Web App/Office Online view of the entire document. Basically, if possible, I'd want to redirect the user to the office web app just as what happens when you're in SharePoint.

I've already implemented CSOM to provide the WOPI link such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026281/how-to-construct-get-office-web-app-url-for-sharepoint-documents):

```
ClientResult<String> result = <file>.ListItemAllFields.GetWOPIFrameUrl(SPWOPIFrameAction.Edit);
```

Problem is the documents are not publicly available. Going to the link prompts for a username and password. I already have the SharepointOnlineCredentials I used for `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` and would like to programmatically sign-in the user using those same credentials.

Reasons:

1. Sign-in account set in the credentials is a "guest account" so that non-microsoft and non-sharepoint users could access the document. Thus, can't sign in.
2. Sharepoint site is not and cannot be a public site that allows anonymous users.
3. Also, trying to avoid the use of OAuth and Active Directory.

Is there any way to do this with REST/CSOM/JSOM? Or other APIs?